# Pass data between two activities in android using HashMap

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to pass data between two activities in my android application and I want to use **HashMap** (I don't want to use **Intent**). Here are my codes:

**DataHolder.java**

```
public final class DataHolder {
    private static Map<String, WeakReference<Object>> data = new HashMap<String, WeakReference<Object>>();

    public static void setF_TaskId(int F_TaskId) {
        data.put("F_TaskId", new WeakReference<Object>(F_TaskId));
    }

    public static int getF_TaskId() {
        WeakReference<Object> objectWeakReference = data.get("F_TaskId");
        return (Integer)objectWeakReference.get();
    }
}
```

**Set value in first activity**

```
DataHolder.setF_TaskId(TaskId);
```

**Get value in other activity**

```
F_TaskId = DataHolder.getF_TaskId();
```

And when I use this for pass data between activity1 to activity2 it will work but after that when pass data between activity2 to activity3, `objectWeakReference.get()` return null so cast to `(Integer)` cause error.
And in activity2 I set data again for activity3. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you removing activity1 data from Map when putting activity2 data?

Comment: no, Just set it again for activity3

Comment: Then what u get when using data.get("F_TaskId") in getF_TaskId() method? print your objectWeakReference before calling get() in getF_TaskId() method.

Comment: You need to check libraries like Otto.

Comment: when I define HashMap value as WeakReference, In second call it clear the value when reach to 'setContentView', So I define that as an Object and problem solved

Comment: Create Singleton and use it. It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `WeakReference<Object>` will clear the `data` variable in `DataHolder` class when code reach to `setContentView(R.layout.Some_Activity)` line in second activity. So I use `Object` instead of `WeakReference<Object>` .

**DataHolder.java**

```
public final class DataHolder {
    private static Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static void setF_TaskId(int F_TaskId) {
        data.put("F_TaskId", F_TaskId);
    }

    public static int getF_TaskId() {
        Object resault = data.get("F_TaskId");
        return (Integer)resault;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this approach

Set value in first activity

```
public static DataHolder dh = new DataHolder();
DataHolder.setF_TaskId(TaskId);
```

Get value in other activity

```
DataHolder dh = FirstActivity.dh;
F_TaskId = dh.getF_TaskId();
```

Comment: No that not good for me, I want something like session. I solved my problem and explain it in comment above, many tnx